# Which is the "write enable" pin of flash memory in Stratix IV GX?

Tags: fpga, programming, flash, stratix-series-fpga

I am trying to use flash memory in Stratix IV GX fpga kit. For that I went through the pin details of the same. But the I was expecting "write enable" which will determine data is to be written to or read from the memory.

Is it the printing mistake of data sheet or is there other signals to do the same function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [Stratix IV GX FPGA Development Kits](http://www.altera.com/products/devkits/altera/kit-siv-gx.html) web page, you'll find the [Stratix IV GX FPGA Development Board Reference Manual (PDF)](http://www.altera.com/literature/manual/rm_sivgx_fpga_dev_board.pdf) where you'll find the documentation for the MAX II CPLD EPM2210 System Controller beginning on PDF page 15, and the FSM bus flash write enable (FLASH_WEn) in table 2-6 part 3 of 4 on PDF page 18, showing both the MAX II CPLD EPM2210 and EP4SGX230 pin numbers.

In the [Stratix IV GX FPGA Development Kit User Guide (PDF)](http://www.altera.com/literature/ug/ug_sivgx_fpga_dev_kit.pdf) you'll find Appendix A. Programming the Flash Memory Device.

Comment: thnx @david. But why write enable pin number is not in page 70 of same document. Where all other pins related to flash are listed ?